# Flow Mapping Lines by Magnitude

Tags: qgis, cartography, flow-map

[image]

I am attempting to map the flow of remittances into Japan using the FlowMapper plugin in QGIS. When I use the Style--> Advanced--> Size Scale field--> magnitude command, the lines become so thick and varied that they are impossible to distinguish from one another (in fact my map becomes one giant block of "lines"). Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this other than manually changing the size of lines classified under equal intervals?

Is there a way to label the flow lines by country of origin so that the text is in and oriented with the flow line, not located on top (that is, once I'm able to get the flow lines to their desired thickness)?

How do I make the lines curved so they are more aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: A simple work around might be to include a new column in the table reducing the (numerical) size of the variable - that's how I've worked around it in the past. Slightly more programm(ery) would be to use something like the scale_linear command in the pen width in the data defined properties. Curving labels on a line can be done through the label placement options.
As for curving the lines ... I don't know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the developer of the FlowMapper QGIS plugin and glad hearing that you utilize it.

Regarding your questions (based on v0.4 current release);

-You can define proportional width and graduated color to flow lines via the flow line symbology tool under the plugin menu. There are several (eq. interval, defined int., eq. classes, std. dev.) options and a fully manual option too

-Due to limitation of shapefiles, curves cannot be natively stored in shapefiles and FlowMapper can only create one-2-many or many-2-many straight lines between discreete nodes. There is a workaround to bend them by exporting to ESRI geodatabase format and defining geographic coord. sys., however I do not know any solution in QGIS.

- one reminder, flowmapper needs the interaction matrix to be square. (see sample data bundled in the installation folder or plugin zip file)

If you have any further questions, feel free to contact over the email on plugin website http://cempro.dyndns.org